# Artifact Dependency ONLY for the build that triggers the build

Tags: teamcity

In TeamCity, you can setup [Artifact Dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2020.2/dependent-build.html#DependentBuild-ArtifactDependency).  This lets you copy artifacts from another build into the current build.

I am trying to use this with a packaging build.  Basically, I have a bunch of builds that create containers.  After a container build is done, I want the packaging build to be triggered.  The packaging build will create a Helm chart based off the container build that triggered it.  (I have permissions and separation of concerns reasons for keeping this out of the container build.)

So I went into my template for my container builds and had them output the things the package build would need as a build artifact (version, container image name, etc).

I then setup the packaging build with Artifact Dependencies on each of my container builds.  This is what I am observing happens:

1. Run one of the container builds.
2. It finishes and saves off its artifacts.
3. The trigger on the package build sees that a container build is done and fires off a package build.
4. The packaging build starts and copies the artifacts from ALL of the container builds into its build folder.
5. Confusion and sadness because the package build does not know which build caused it to trigger.

The problem is that when I run a container build, it will copy the artifacts from ALL of the container builds into the package build.

**How can I get information from just the container build that triggered the package build (instead of all of the dependencies?**

Answer (score 0):

You can not : by definition, artifacts dependencies are informations you are requiring.

I am unsure whether this answers the question you asked (or the one you did not) : this is not how TeamCity and artifacts work.

Here is the "official" TeamCity way to go : for each of your `create-container` build, write

- a `create-container` build, with a VCS configured but not trigger
- a `package-container` build, with

  - the same VCS configured
  - a VCS trigger (the one that used to be on the `create-container` build)
  - a Snapshot Dependency on the `create-container` : this will ensure this build runs with the same VCS revision as the `create-container` one
  - an artifact dependency on the corresponding `create-container`.

When triggering, the `package-container` will wait for the corresponding `create-container` build to successfully complete, then it will run.

*If* having different `package-container` build run simultaneously is a problem : look into TeamCity's **Shared Resources** Build Feature (create and use one with `quota: 1`).

As for the `package-container` build : instead of copying the build N times, just **Action .. Extract template** from the first and create the N-1 others based on this one. You'll need to alter the dependency for each one, but if you then need to alter them all a simple change to the `Template` will do.